# How to run installation petalinux in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am not able to run the installation of petalinux in Ubuntu 20.04.

```
abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx$ /petalinux-v2021.1-final-installer.run /scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux
```

It comes with this error.

```
-bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

I edit my question with terminal. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx$ ls
Downloads       Petalinux                   petalinux-v2021.1-final-installer.run  Vitis      Vivado
DocNav  Model_Composer  Projects                               Vitis_HLS  xic

abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx$ ./petalinux-v2021.1-final-installer.run /scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux

ERROR: Invalid options: /scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux
PetaLinux installer.
Usage:
  petalinux-v2021.1-final-installer.run [--log <LOGFILE>] [-d|--dir <INSTALL_DIR>] [options]
Options:
  --log <LOGFILE>               specify where the logfile should be created.
                                it will be petalinux_installation_log
                                in your working directory by default.
  -d|--dir [INSTALL_DIR]        specify the directory where you want to
                                install the tool kit. If not specified,
                                it will install to your working directory.
  -p|--platform <arch_name>     specify the architecture name.
                                aarch64         : sources for zynqMP and versal
                                arm             : sources for zynq
                                microblaze_lite : sources for microblaze_lite
                                microblaze_full : sources for microblaze_full
EXAMPLES:
Install the tool in specified location:
 $ ./petalinux-v2021.1-final-installer.run -d/--dir <INSTALL_DIR>
To get only desired sources:
 $ ./petalinux-v2021.1-final-installer.run --dir <INSTALL_DIR>
        This will install the sources for all(zynq,zynqMP,versal,microblaze_lite,microblaze_full).

 $ ./petalinux-v2021.1-final-installer.run --dir <INSTALL_DIR> --platform "arm"
        This will install the sources for zynq only.

 $ ./petalinux-v2021.1-final-installer.run --dir <INSTALL_DIR> --platform "arm aarch64"
        This will install the sources for zynq,zynqMP and versal.

 $ ./petalinux-v2021.1-final-installer.run --dir <INSTALL_DIR> --platform "microblaze_lite microblaze_full"
        This will install the sources for microblaze_lite
Please refer to the PetaLinux Tools Installation Guide.
```

Comment: Did you look to see if you have that directory and or file?

Comment: Yes the installation file is located at the location "abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx"

Comment: No the error says this dir or file is missing /usr/bin/python

Comment: I am still not able to run installation. Kindly have a look at my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to install Python3 symlink (*/usr/bin/python* → */usr/bin/python3*) by

```
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
```

and then retry running installer.

Also consult with https://xilinx.github.io/kria-apps-docs/main/build/html/docs/build_petalinux.html .

Comment: I have installed python using `sudo apt-get install python-is-python3` and the python3 is located in the location  /usr/bin/python3. But when I run the command to start installation, I get this error.    
`-bash: /petalinux-v2021.1-final-installer.run: No such file or directory`. There is plenty of space available in /scratch2, around 300 GB and I guess the petalinux need 100 GB free in the drive.

Comment: The path `/petalinux-v2021.1-final-installer.run` is probably wrong, you have to change directory to petalinux file and the run it using `./petalinux-v2021.1-final-installer.run` .

Answer (score -3):

Step 1: Create the Virtual Machine

```
Download, install and launch VirtualBox from here.
Create a new virtual machine using these options:
    Linux
    Ubuntu 64-bit
    16 GB RAM (8GB minimum according to user guide)
    VirtualBox Disk Image
    Dynamic (resizable) hard disk
    200 GB size (the resulting VM will have about 113GB free after all of these installs so you can reduce this if you like)
```

I recommend using the dynamic type of hard disk because the Xilinx tools use up a lot of space, BSPs can take up a couple of GB each, plus PetaLinux projects use up a lot of space typically, so it’s hard to know exactly how much space you will end up needing. If you go with a fixed size HDD, you can’t change it easily with VirtualBox, so I say go with the dynamic.

More about please visit h[ttps://www.fpgadeveloper.com/how-to-install-petalinux-2020.1/](https://www.fpgadeveloper.com/how-to-install-petalinux-2020.1/)